# wampserver has some problems with opening php files

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, wampserver

I downloaded a source code for designing a online store and I wanted to run php file with wampserver.At first I copied php files and pasted in www folder in wampserver then I typed
127.0.0.1/abc

in my browser but I saw this:
 Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'shop_sc'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\abc\db_fns.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\abc\db_fns.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'shop_sc'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\abc\db_fns.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\abc\db_fns.php on line 8

I dont know what should I do?

this is db_fns.php file:

```
 <?php

function db_connect()
{
   $result = new mysqli('localhost', 'shop_sc', 'password', 'shop_sc'); 
   if (!$result)
      return false;
    $result->query('SET NAMES utf8'); 
   return $result;
}

function db_result_to_array($result)
{
   $res_array = array();

   for ($count=0; $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $count++)
     $res_array[$count] = $row;

   return $res_array;
}

?>
```

Comment: I think the server is apache

Comment: yes,but i dont know where is the problem,i know code is right and it hasnt problem ,there is some problem in my work but i dont know where is it?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't configured MySQL for this store. Often packages like these will have an install script that will run and setup the tables and users in your database, is there anything like that with this package?

Comment: yes,it was a ready code.it has a sql file and i pasted in www folder but it doesnt work.

Comment: so in your MySQL database, a user "shop_sc" already exists with the correct password and table permissions? Because usually you only get that error if a) you have the wrong password b) invalid username c) are connecting from a restricted ip or host d) the user account doesnt have basic usage permissions

Comment: have you activated them (apache and mysql server)?

Comment: What is the package called? It's quite obvious that you have not created the MySQL database for the package. Not created the default user account on MySQL for the package. And probably not run the initial database creation script. So tell us the package name and we can point you to the Installation instructions.

Comment: what do u mean exactly? the name of this package is  online store,just this.

Comment: if u want I can mail compelet package for u

Comment: You should know at least a little bit about PHP and databases....

Comment: Sara, post the url you used to download the store, there must be some installation instructions on there somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

In the config file, C:\wamp\www\abc\db_fns.php , look for "shop_sc". This is the user that tries to connect to your database.

Look for the database name and password if any in the file. It may be blank too. Now login to mysql from backend.

For this, open cmd and run `mysql -u root -h localhost -p <password_if_any>`.

Once you are logged in change the password for shop_sc user as mentioned in the config file above.

Else the simplest option is to set the password for shop_sc as "". I mean no password. Let us know if it helps.

Editing my answer .

Riggsfolly may be correct when he says that mysql may not be in your path. So if wamp doesn't add it in your path on installation, you can add it in you PATH. Not a big thing to do. Once done so, you may have to.

1) Set up your root password because it looks like you did a fresh installation. So open your command line and go to **C:\wamp\bin\mysql\\bin**

2) Then run mysqladmin like this to set up the password for root user : `mysqladmin -u root password <your_NEW_PASSWORD_here>`

3) Now login into mysql server by typing : `mysql -h localhost -u root -p` Enter and then key in your password.

4) Now once you are logged in, create your user, shop_sc with

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<set_password_here>';
```

Comment: Are you for real, this kids greener than Kermit and you are telling her this. Oh by the way WAMPServer is a windows installation of AMP so the mysql processor wont be on the path and this will not work anyway.

Comment: I edited my post and I  wrote  db_fns.php file,but how can I change my password by this file.plz help me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, RiggsFolly. Sara - I have put the tested steps there up.

Answer (score 0):

Update connection username, password and database name

Comment: To what? Where and how?

Comment: You can start looking at C:\wamp\www\abc\db_fns.php on line 5